# Python Pandas identify changes in values across rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a table like this:

```
CustomerID, ProfileID, ProductID, Date,       % Amount Change
1234,       4313,      41,        2013-08-01, -0.01
270,        13,        1,         2011-08-01, 10.453
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-05-01, -0.474
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-06-01, -0.619
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-07-01, -0.419
```

I need to flag all records in groups of CustomerID-ProfileID-ProductID where there are at least three consecutive months of -1 in the % Amount Change field.

In this example:

```
 CID   PID,  PRID        DATE  % Amt Change
1234, 4313,   41,  2011-11-01,   -0.414
1234, 4313,   41,  2011-12-01,   -0.354
1234, 4313,   41,  2012-01-01,   -0.676
1234, 4313,   41,  2012-02-01,   -0.874
2313, 3311,   41,  2014-05-01,   0.5
```

I would like to flag each of the first four records and ignore the fifth record.

While I do know how to do this if I were to simply iterate through all records,I would love to know a Pandas way to do this. While I've read about "shift" and other functions, I'm not entirely sure how to tie it all together. I assume I would start with something like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['CID,PID,'PRID'])
```

but I'm confused from there.

Comment: Not clear about what you said: **-1** in the % Amount Change, do you mean 1% or 100%?

Comment: That is the output of .pct_change() and I meant 10% decrease

Answer (score 0):

Using data in your first table as `df`, this is is one way to do it:

```
groups = df.groupby(['CustomerID','ProfileID','ProductID'])
df[groups["% Amount Change"].apply(lambda x: x < -0.01)]
```

yields:

```
   CustomerID  ProfileID  ProductID                 Date  % Amount Change
2        8734       3000          5           2014-05-01           -0.474
3        8734       3000          5           2014-06-01           -0.619
4        8734       3000          5           2014-07-01           -0.419
```

Which looks like what you wanted.

However it is not clear why do you need to group if the same result is achieved with simple filtering:

```
df[df["% Amount Change"] < -0.01]
```

EDIT:

To have full control of the "consequence" of the data here is solution I came down to.
I had modified your data a bit to check more cases:

```
data = """CustomerID,ProfileID,ProductID,Date,% Amount Change
1234,       4313,      41,        2013-12-02, -0.01
270,        13,        1,         2011-12-03, 10.453
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-04, 0.474
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-05, -0.474
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-06, -0.619
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-07, 0.620
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-08, -0.621
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-09, -0.622
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-10, -0.623
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-11, 0.623
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-12, -0.623
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-13, -0.623
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-14, -0.623
8734,       3000,      5,         2014-12-15, -0.419"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

Set the filter level and how long the sequence should be:

```
Filter = -0.01
ConseqN = 3
```

Insert columns with boolean value to indicate the sequences of data that passes the filter:

```
df['F'] = (df['% Amount Change'] < Filter).astype(int)
```

Group consecutive data in batches to enable measuring length of each one:

```
groups = df.groupby(['CustomerID','ProfileID','ProductID'])
df['batch'] = groups['F'].apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).astype(int).cumsum())
```

Build list of batches with required length (`ConseqN`):

```
groups = df[df['F']==1].groupby(['CustomerID','ProfileID','ProductID','batch'])
df[df['batch'].isin([n[3] for n, g in groups if len(g) == ConseqN])]
```

The output with 1 batches (with 3 consecutive observations):

```
   CustomerID  ProfileID  ProductID                 Date  % Amount Change  F  batch
6        8734       3000          5           2014-12-08           -0.621  1      4
7        8734       3000          5           2014-12-09           -0.622  1      4
8        8734       3000          5           2014-12-10           -0.623  1      4
```

Note that it ignored the batch with 4 consecutive observations that passed the filter (not sure if this is actually needed, but this can be easily changed).

And there is probably a way to simplify the last part of the process which is dealing with catching batches of the right length...

Comment: Thank you, Primer. Actually, I don't need grouping per se. The ultimate goal is to flag records that are in a group of three or more consecutive months with a -.1 or less value in % Amount Change.  So basically, if there is a decline in value of 10% or more month-over-month.

Comment: So in your example, how do I know that I have three consecutive months?

Comment: Sorry, the word "consecutive" conveniently slipped my attention...
I have modified an answer to take this important word into account

Comment: Ok - it seems like this gets me close. But when I say "consecutive" I'm referring to consecutive months and not days. And in most cases, there will not be more than one consecutive month (because it was a positive month instead of being "-1", or because there were simply no data for a month.)  So a simple sort won't work, I also need to be sure there is not a break in the year-month sequence.